# Runnable::new vs new Runnable()

Tags: java, java-8, runnable, constructor-reference

Why doesn't the first of the following examples work?

- `run(R::new);` method `R.run` is not called.
- `run(new R());` method `R.run` **is** called.

Both examples are compiled-able.

```
public class ConstructorRefVsNew {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(R::new);
      System.out.println("-----------------------");
      new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(new R());
  }

  void run(Runnable r) {
      r.run();
  }

  static class R implements Runnable {

      R() {
          System.out.println("R constructor runs");
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("R.run runs");
      }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
  R constructor runs
  -----------------------
  R constructor runs
  R.run runs
```

In the first example, the `R` constructor is called, it returns lambda (which is not object):

[image]

But then how is it possible, that the example is compiled successfully?

Comment: Note that  `Runnable runnable = R::new;`  `runnable instanceof R` -> false

Comment: I don't know about Java specifically but `new` is usually an indicator that you want to allocate some memory that you promise you will clean up yourself. `R::new` just sounds like a factory method, a static function in R that creates and returns an instance of Runnable. If this instance is not captured by assigning it to a variable it might be cleaned up the moment it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 57):

Your `run` method takes a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) instance, and that explains why `run(new R())` works with the `R` implementation.

`R::new` is not equivalent to `new R()`. It can fit the signature of a `Supplier<Runnable>` (or similar functional interfaces), but `R::new` cannot be used as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) implemented with your `R` class.

A version of your `run` method that can take`R::new` could look like this (but this would be unnecessarily complex):

```
void run(Supplier<Runnable> r) {
    r.get().run();
}
```

> Why does it compile?

Because the compiler can make a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) out of the constructor call, and that would be equivalent to this lambda expression version:

```
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(() -> {
    new R(); //discarded result, but this is the run() body
});
```

The same applies to these statements:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> new R();
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(runnable);
Runnable runnable2 = R::new;
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(runnable2);
```

But, as you can notice, the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) created with `R::new` does just call `new R()` in its `run` method body.

---

A valid use of a method reference to execute `R#run` could use an instance, like this (but you'd surely rather use the `r` instance directly, in this case):

```
R r = new R();
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(r::run);
```

Comment: Should we assume, that java compiler created from my method run(Runnable r) -> run(Supplier<Runnable> r)?

Comment: @user1722245 I edited the answer. The compiler made `() -> {new R();}` out of `R::new` in that context.

Answer (score 24):

The first example:

```
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(R::new);
```

is more or less equivalent to:

```
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run( () -> {new R();} );
```

The effect is you just create an instance of R but do not call its `run` method.

Comment: It means, that I have two nested runnable. On the first method run is called only.

Answer (score 10):

Compare two calls:

```
((Runnable)() -> new R()).run();
new R().run();
```

By `((Runnable)() -> new R())` or `((Runnable) R::new)` , you create **a new `Runnable`** which does nothing<sup>1</sup>.

By `new R()`, you create **an instance of the `R` class** where the `run` method is well-defined.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Actually, it creates an object of `R` which has no impact on execution.</sup>

---

I was thinking of treating 2 invocations identically without modifying the `main` method. We would need to overload `run(Runnable)` with `run(Supplier<Runnable>)`.

```
class ConstructorRefVsNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(R::new);
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(new R());
    }

    void run(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }

    void run(Supplier<Runnable> s) {
        run(s.get());
    }

    static class R implements Runnable { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `run` method expects a `Runnable`.

The easy case is `new R()`. In this case you know the result is an object of type `R`. `R` itself is a runnable, it has a `run` method, and that's how Java sees it.

But when you pass `R::new` something else is happening. What you tell it is to create an anonymous object compatible with a `Runnable` whose `run` method runs the operation you passed it.

The operation you passed it is not `R`'s `run` method. The operation is the costructor of `R`. Thus, it's like you have passed it an anonymous class like:

```
new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
         new R();
     }
}
```

(Not all the details are the same, but this is the closest "classical" Java construct ).

`R::new`, when called, calls `new R()`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here to give a more readable answer, for people are new to java lambda world.

## What's this

- `R::new` is using `method reference`, which emerged from java8, let you reuse existing method definitions and pass them just like lambdas. So when you write `Runnable::new`, actually it means `() -> new R()`, the result is a lambda;
- `new R()` is calling the constructor of class `R`, and return an instance of that class, the result is a instance of `R`.

We are now clear about what are them, but how they works(why they are compiled-able)?

## How it works

For `new R()`, it's very easy to understand what happened and I'll leave without explanation.

For `Runnable::new` which stands for `() -> new R()`, we need to know that `Runnable` is what we called the `FunctionalInterface`, and a functional interface is a interface with only one method, when we pass lambda to a method that accepts a functional interface as parameter, the lambda must matches the signature of that interface, and the action in lambda is filled to the body of that method.

The `Runnable` in `JDK11` looks like this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {

    public abstract void run();
}
```

while the lambda `() -> new R()` is compatible with the method signature - accept nothing and return nothing, so the code works, and in this case, the runTime object of the passed-in parameter looks like this:

```java
Runnable instance with run method {

    public void run() {
      new R();
    };
}
```

now we get to know why in this situation, only construction of `R` triggered.

## What's more

We can achieve what `run(new R())` does with lambda like this:

```java
new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(() -> System.out.println("R.run runs"));
```

I finally realize the question comes very tricky that the given lambda `Runnable::new` is actually compatible with `Runnable` interface. You can define a customize functional interface called `Foo` or whatever  to do the same thing

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Foo{

    public abstract void run();
}

public class ConstructorRefVsNew {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ConstructorRefVsNew().run(R::new);
  }

  void run(Foo f) {
      f.run();
  }
}
```

and in this case, the `R::new` still works well while the `new R()` cannot be passed, which indicates that the question is not a big deal but a fascinating coincidence.